# Whole Page CSS Background Image

Tags: css

If I have a large image to be used as `background-image` for my html pages, how to make the entire page load faster? What are the best practices for having a large background-image?

Thanks

Comment: Try to add your research and effort so that community will know the already tried solution and will provide new solution.

Answer (score 2):

The best practice is to have a small background-image. If you have a background-image that repeats, please try to restrict it to the smallest repeating unit; CSS will automatically repeat the image infinitely in both x and y directions. '

If you have a non-repeating background image, then you obviously can't crop the image to make it smaller. In that case, you may want to set `background-size:cover` and `background-repeat:no-repeat` so the entire image fills the whole scree without repeating. The best practice here would probably be to use some high-compression file, like a JPEG instead of a PNG.

Answer (score 1):

Compress the image as much as possible. Your bottleneck is the data transfer over the wire - pages wait for CSS to finish loading to be "ready" so the fewer bytes that need to be transferred, the better. Alternatively, you could store your static assets on a CDN like Akamai which will serve it up blazingly fast from a much closer location to the user.